# Mamp 3 - apache won't start on port 8888

Tags: apache, mamp, osx-mavericks

Running Mavericks and I just upgraded to Mamp 3. I can't get apache to start using the default port of 8888. Runs fine on port 80, and all ran smoothly using Mamp 2.

Restarting Apache using SUDO doesn't work. I used "sudo apachectl stop" but this had no effect.

Error logs show nothing. when I switch to port 80 and MySQL port 3306, it all starts, but I don't want it to use port 80. Thanks.

Comment: If there really is no entry in the main error log file of the http server after a restart, then the server listens on the specified port. Might it be that you have a network problem? A firewall blocking access to that non standard port?

Comment: The installation is on localhost. As I said, the previous version of MAMP worked fine, but I'd like to apply the upgrade and use port 8888 for Apache.

Answer (score 2):

i have found this solution it worked for me i hope it helps you :

Just navigate to /Applications/MAMP/bin/apache2/bin using Finder, and rename envvars to _envvars (yes, just add the underscore). Boom! Done and done.

http://codesoap.com/mamp-pro-apache-and/

Comment: For some reason this fixed the Apache issue but created a MySQL issue of the same nature

Comment: Worked fine,,, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people have success with this answer http://aralbalkan.com/1931/
It didn't work for me however, I have exactly the same issue, I upgraded and now can't run it on port 8888 which means none of my local SilverStripe sites are working!! Did you find any other solution?

Comment: I finally fixed mine by removing (not deleting) all old versions completely from the Applications folder and then re-installing it. I then when in to the old MAMP folder and copy and pasted the db folder to the new MAMP folder which moved the databases successfully. (If you don't move the entire folder there can be issue with tables not appearing).